# Use jQuery to select divs that have html entities

Tags: jquery, html, contains, html-entities

I need to select all `divs` that contain `&lt;sup&gt;`.

I already tried

```
var size = $("div:contains('&lt;sup&gt;')").length;
```

With the code above I get a length of `0`.

#### Sample HTML

```
<div>I have a &lt;sup&gt;superscript&lt;/sup&gt;!</div>
```

Comment: What is your HTML?

Comment: @nicael I edited the question to show a sample input.

Comment: Try $("div").filter() http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:contains()` already escapes the entities for you.

```js
var size = $("div:contains('<sup>')").length;
console.log(size);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>I have a &lt;sup&gt;superscript&lt;/sup&gt;!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

While you've already accepted an answer, I thought I'd take a moment to show you a slightly more easily-customisable approach, which allows you to find – and retrieve – all child elements held within the text of an element (as your title suggests you want: "*Use [jQuery] to select [`<div>` elements] that have html entities*"), or which allows you to filter for a specific type of element within those  elements (as the first line of your question implies you want: "*I need to select all [`<div>` elements] that contain <sup>.*").

That said, the following covers both situations using plain JavaScript:

```
// str:       String, the textContent of a given node.
// filterFor: String, the tag-name of an element-type
//            for which you wish to search (eg: 'div',
//            'sup' etc).
function hasEntities(str, filterFor) {

  // a temporary element to contain the supplied string
  // of text:
  var temp = document.createElement('div'),

  // a variable to hold the child elements of the
  // temp element (to be used later):
    parsed;

  // assigning the text as the innerHTML of the
  // created element:
  temp.innerHTML = str;

  // finding all elements contained within the created-
  // element, using the CSS universal selector ('*');
  // and converting that collection into an Array, using
  // Array.from:
  parsed = Array.from( temp.querySelectorAll('*') );

  // if a filterFor argument was supplied:
  if (filterFor) {

    // we first remove all '<', '/' and '>' characters from
    // the supplied string, replacing them with an empty-
    // String, and then convert it to lower-case:
    filterFor = filterFor.replace(/(<|\/|>)+/g, '').toLowerCase();

    // here we filter the array of nodes using
    // Array.prototype.filter() to discard all elements
    // for which the assessment does not return true
    // or truthy; and then return that filtered
    // array to the calling context:
    return parsed.filter(function(n) {

      // if the current element of the Array of element
      // nodes found within the created-element, in
      // lower-case, is equal to the element-type we're
      // looking for then we retain that node, otherwise
      // it's discarded:
      return n.tagName.toLowerCase() === filterFor;
    });
  }

  // if no filterFor argument was supplied then we simply
  // return the array of descendant elements:
  return parsed;
}

var el = document.querySelector('div'),
  parentOfSup = hasEntities(el.textContent, 'sup').length > 0;

console.log(parentOfSup); // returns the <sup> node
console.log(parentOfSup.length); // 1
console.log(parentOfSup.length > 0); // true
```

```js
function hasEntities(str, filterFor) {
  var temp = document.createElement('div'),
    parsed;

  temp.innerHTML = str;

  parsed = Array.from(temp.getElementsByTagName('*'));

  if (filterFor) {
    filterFor = filterFor.replace(/(<|\/|>)+/g, '').toLowerCase();

    return parsed.filter(function(n) {
      return n.tagName.toLowerCase() === filterFor;
    });
  }

  return parsed;
}

var el = document.querySelector('div'),
  parentOfSup = hasEntities(el.textContent, 'sup').length > 0;

console.log(parentOfSup);
```

```html
<div>I have a &lt;sup&gt;superscript&lt;/sup&gt;&lt;div&gt;and a child div&lt;/div&gt;!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) all divs that contain the characters & and ;

```
var divs = $("div").filter(function(idx) {
   return this.innerHTML.indexOf("&") > -1 && this.innerHTML.indexOf(";") > -1;
});
```